# Disable all buttons whose ID attribute begins with

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a table on it.  The table lists multiple rows each one with a 'Create' button.  The table itself uses a `for` loop and appends the rows value to the end of the buttons ID as shown below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="create_<%: stck.Stock%>" onclick="SetupDisinvestmentsFields(this,'<%=stck.SEDOL%>','<%=stck.Quantity%>','<%=stck.value%>')">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
</button>
```

My full code for the table is

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>SEDOL</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
     <%
        foreach (var stck in stocks)
        { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%: stck.Stock%></td>
                <td><%: stck.SEDOL%></td>
                <td><%: stck.Quantity%></td>
                <td><%: String.Format("{0:c}", stck.value)%></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="create_<%: stck.Stock%>" onclick="SetupDisinvestmentsFields(this,'<%=stck.SEDOL%>','<%=stck.Quantity%>','<%=stck.value%>')">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% }
    %>
</table>
```

What I want is when the page state changes for all the 'Create' buttons to be disabled in the table.

I have tried the following but it only disables the first button and not the rest

```
document.querySelector('[id^="create_"]').disabled = true;
```

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and a `for` loop (be aware that `querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList and you will have to use `.item(i)` to retrieve the item at position `i`). Pure JS is not jQuery so you have to apply it to every element, you can;t apply it to a group of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.querySelector` only returns the first matched element. You need to instead use `document.querySelectorAll` and then loop through the resulting NodeList instead:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="create_"]');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: For querySelectorAll it's advised to us `elems.item(i)` to retrieve the actual item as its a Non Live NodeList (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: @somethinghere as far as I'm aware the `item()` method is only recommended to avoid `i` targeting an out of bounds index. In this situation I don't think it matters as we're predetermining the NodeList's length. **Edit:** In fact, that's pretty much exactly what the page you've linked says: "can be used as an alternative to simply accessing nodeList[idx] (which instead returns  undefined when idx is out-of-bounds)".

Comment: Hmmm. I'd err on the side of safety, but yeah, fine. Just mentioning it.

Comment: Just for completeness sake since the question mentions it explicitly: document.querySelectorAll('button[id^="create_"]')